# Trigger event on click except for checkbox + label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table row, which triggers an event when clicked. There are (not displayed) checkbox + its styled label inside the row.

What i want is to prevent (i guess with :not or .not() but cant figure it out) the execution if checkbox/label is clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<center>
<table>
    <tr class='pend'>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="bb"/> <label for="bb">X</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

**CSS:**

```
center {
margin-top:20px;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:red;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

table tr {
height:40px;
    background-color:gray;
}

table td {
padding:5px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.pend').on('click',function(){
    $(this).append('text');
    return false;
})
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ySuGB/2/

Comment: so the execution needs to happen when row is clicked, but not checkbox or label?

Comment: @sweettea Yes, except checkbox/label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent event bubbling on click of checkbox/label.

See below,

```
//                     V-- Is the TD containing the checkbox and the label.
$('.pend :checkbox').parent().on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ySuGB/12/

Answer (score 1):

e.stopPropagation() is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/jNDYJ/

```
$('.pend input:checkbox').add('.pend label[for=bb]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if event target is label (etc):

```
$('.pend').on('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName=='LABEL')
    return false;
  $(this).append('text');
  return false;
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ySuGB/9/

Comment: `e.target.tagName=='LABEL' || e.target.tagName=='INPUT'` <-- You missed the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pend').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.off('click');
    $this.find('td:eq(2)').append('text');
})​
```